# using UUID as id in JPA / Hibernate on Oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    private String name; 
}
```

And corresponding table in Oracle; `RAW(16)` for UUID

```
create TABLE STUDENT (
 id RAW(16) PRIMARY key,
 name VARCHAR2(100)
)
```

When I try to persist a new entry I get

```
insert into STUDENT (name, id) values (?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [John Doe]
binding parameter [2] as [BINARY] - [07fccb6b-d0b2-4946-a752-ecfabc315589]

SQL Error: 932, SQLState: 42000
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY
```

What is the matching datatype in Oracle for UUID ? Or is it necessary to setup some sort of converter to get this going ?

This is in a Spring boot 2.3.0 project with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.3.0 which pulls in spring 5.2.6 and hibernate 5.4.15
and Oracle 12.2

I have enabled batch in hibernate and some other settings for debugging

```
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", false);
    properties.put("hibernate.type", "trace");
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "10");
    properties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");
```

UPDATE:
As suggested in one of the comments this example works without issues. This was a simplified scenario of a problem I had, and the original problem was solved once I dropped and recreated all the tables. I have been unable to replicate since. I dont have any fitting explanation to why this happened but I did change the type for ID from Integer to RAW(16) and there was a trigger for auto increment.

Comment: I tried to use your table definition and entity mapping and it worked fine for me. Are you sure that your `STUDENT.id` was declared as you mentioned?

Comment: What hibernate version, dialect do you use? It would be nice to see your hibernate config parameters.

Comment: @SternK this is snippet from a larger project, just pulled in relevant snippets for this question. I have edited the question to add version and config details as well

Comment: @SternK you were right, this simplified example does run without errors. my actual scenario does contain some relations but since the first insert was failing i thought this would replicate the problem. will try to replicate my original issue and update the question. thanks for your effort much appreciated.