# Java hibernate storing a uuid2 in oracle database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am storing a value in the oracle db table
Table column

```
id VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL
```

Java code

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_TEST_1", schema = "QA")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class TestUuid implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private java.util.UUID id;
```

To save i use a repository interface and do a save

When the saved entity is passed i get the uuid as `61adf93b-b76d-4b38-a43a-ffc033ad4cea`
but it is stored in the db as `61ADF93BB76D4B38A43AFFC033AD4CEA` and when i do a find using JPA it gives totally another value `36314144-4639-3342-4237-364434423338`

It retrieves the value correctly using native query though

Can you let me know why i notice the anomaly

Thanks

Comment: Similar: [*using UUID as id in JPA / Hibernate on Oracle*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62560495/642706) and [*UUID data type in Oracle*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73659002/642706).

Comment: You have not stated the version of Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

in oracle field type must be RAW(16).
If you use liquibase, you can set type as UUID and it will be created as RAW(16) in oracle